# Conformal mapping of non-convex finite domain

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Can a non-convex finite domain be conformally mapped to the unit circle?

I am interested in finding such map for this one: a square of length 1 with quarter circles of radius 1/3 removed from each corner.

[image: a square with sides of length 1, with quarter circles of radius 1/3 removed from each corner]

Comment: By the Riemann mapping theorem, you can map it conformally to the unit disk. Maybe there is even some more or less explicit formula for it, the boundary is simple enough that there might be.